# How to simplify the filter code for given days

Tags: r, tidyverse, as.date

When filter some days value from dataframe, I have to repeat 'as.Date' many times in filter condition sentence.
Is there any way to simplify it?  Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(mday=seq.Date(as.Date('2021-1-1'),
                        as.Date('2021-12-30'),by="1 day"),
                        value=rnorm(364))
# can't work
test_data %>% filter(mday %in% c(as.Date('2021-1-1','2021-7-1','2021-10-7')))

# can work, but have to repeat 'as.date' many times
test_data %>% filter(mday %in% c(as.Date('2021-1-1'),
                                 as.Date('2021-7-1'),
                                 as.Date('2021-10-7')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. Should be:

```
test_data %>% filter(mday %in% as.Date(c('2021-1-1','2021-7-1','2021-10-7')))
```

It is because at first you need to create a vector, i.e. use `c()` function and then you can perform modifications on this vector, in your case - change vector to `date`.

Comment: This what I want .Thanks!